# having trouble drawing a rectangle to the screen ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am following a video tutorial from pluralsight that draws a red rectangle to the screen. I have a subclass of UIView called PSViewDemo that has the following code in the .m file:

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(40, 400,100,200));
    // Drawing code
}
```

I call it in the Viewdidload of the viewcontroller for the only view in the application (until the code adds the subview).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    PSViewDemo *dv = [[PSViewDemo alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:dv];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The whole thing compiles and runs without error but there is no red rectangle on the screen.

What am I missing? I am pretty sure I am following the tutorial exactly so maybe something has changed in Cocoa since the tutorial was made? I'm using xCode 5.

Comment: `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);` or use `CGColorGetComponents` as shown in the answer below.

Comment: I read in docs today that `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor()` is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
CGContextSetFillColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
```

To

```
CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor redColor] CGColor]));
```